# Utorrent unable to load "file" : Access denied

Tags: mount, hard-drive, storage, utorrent

So Iam new to Ubuntu. I think I have managed to mount my additional internal hard disk drive. I can download everything to it from Google chrome and view it from Files,however I still think that other applications don't recognize the HDD such as Utorrent. I tried uploading to it files from the HDD but the hard disk is not even visible from the storage options. So anybody have an idea what might be the problem??